# How to initialize Email without hardcoding using sendgrid with java

Tags: java, spring, sendgrid

How can I initialize email in my service class without hardcoding(eg : `Email to = new Email("1234@gmail.com")`. I use the following code to initialize my email but it returns some error. Help me to fix this. I'm using SendGrid API. Here is my service code:

```
Email to = new Email();

to.setEmail(emailIDTO.getTO());  //emailIDTO is an object of IDTO class
// IDTO class takes the value from the JSON request body and initializes it to the email object
```

And the relevant IDTO snippet:

```
public Email getTo(){ 
    return to; 
} // method getTo return the mail id of the recipient. 

public Email createTo(EmailIDTO emailIDTO){ 
   to.setName(emailIDTO.getName(); 
   to.setEmail(emailIDTO.getEmail()); 
   return null; 
}
```

Error :

`setEmail (java.lang.String) in Email cannot be applied to (com.sendgrid.Email)`

Comment: Hi, please include the details of the error you're getting. Also explain what do you mean by "without hardcoding"? And what's an IDTO class? If you include more details in your question, someone will surely help you. In the meanwhile please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for making the question unclear. I have made the changes you said. @Michal

Comment: Excellent, now we're getting somewhere. Can you also include a snippet of your `emailIDTO.getTO()` method. The error indicates a type mismatch between your helper method return type and the expected parameter of `setEmail`.

Comment: public Email getTo(){ return to; } // method getTo return the mail id of the recipient.  public Email createTo(EmailIDTO emailIDTO){ to.setName(emailIDTO.getName(); to.setEmail(emailIDTO.getEmail()); return null; }

Comment: I updated your question again to include the relevant code. Please take a note of that when asking future questions. If you find my answer below helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing because your `emailIDTO.getTO()` method is returning Email object, which you are trying to assign using method that accepts String parameter. The error is pretty self-explanatory in this case.

You can try one of the following:

Option 1 - set object directly from IDTO:

```
Email to = emailIDTO.getTO();
```

Option 2 - extract the string value:

```
Email to = new Email();
to.setEmail(emailIDTO.getTO().getEmail());
```

Caution - your `IDTO.createTo()` method returns null, which may have unexpected consequences. Perhaps you wanted to return `to`?

Comment: Thank you very much....Sorry for making the question unclear. I'm newbie to stack overflow and software development . I will follow the tips correctly for the next time.